# Polynomial multiplication in Prolog

Tags: prolog, multiplication, polynomials

I tried to write a predicate that performs the multiplication of two polynomials, but work only when it receives only monomials.
This is the code:
[Code Monomial + Polinomial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZyB9.png) , 
[Code Multiplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjEvg.png)

Answer:

```
1 ?- polytimes(2*a*c,4*b*e,A).
A = poly([m(8, 4, [v(1, a), v(1, c), v(1, b), v(1, e)])]).

2 ?- polytimes(3*a*c,2*b,A).
A = poly([m(6, 3, [v(1, a), v(1, c), v(1, b)])]).

3 ?- polytimes(2*a + z,4*b*e,A).
A = poly([m(8, 4, [v(1, a), v(1, z), v(1, b), v(1, e)])]).
```

I want to know if you had any help about it.

Comment: Don't post your code as an image, thanks!

Comment: And please try to find out first if the bug is in the translation arithmetic terms to the internal polynomial representation, or in the code for multiplying polynomials in that representation.